# Does enemy team gain solar when Ayla or Clunck kill themselves?

Tags: awesomenauts

I'm trying to evaluate the following scenario:

I'm playing with Ayla and she is in Rage and I notice that she's gonna die either way, if she remains in rage she'd kill herself and if she comes out of rage an enemy Awesomenaut would kill her. The question is, which decision yelids the least solar to the opposite team?

When she kills herself she drops 30 solar on the floor but if the enemy awesomenaut kills her every enemy awesomenaut get 30 solar (total of 90)

So my question is, if she kills herself does enemy awesomenauts gain the 90 solar as well as the 30 on the floor or is it just the 30 on the floor?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you die:

#### For every death, no matter how you died (killed by droid, other awesomenaut, or suicide):

- You lose 30 solar.
- Each enemy receives 30 solar

So the above happens no matter what, every time you die. In addition to the above:

#### Killed by enemy awesomenaut:

- The killer receives 30 solar

#### Other deaths (droid, suicide, any other reason other than death to enemy awesomenaut)

- You drop 30 solar on the floor

So the total amount of solar up for grabs and lost by you is the same in all cases.  It only differs in how it's distributed.
Meaning, it's better to not be killed by an enemy awesomenaut, because there is a chance that the 30 solar dropped on the ground can be picked up by teammates or left on the ground, rather than going straight to an enemy.
 So suicide or dead by droid is a slightly better option.  That's the only difference though.

Comment: currently nothing drops on the floor.

Answer (score 1):

The enemy awesomenauts do NOT receive solar, as it the solar they receive is a reward for killing an opponent. The stuff you drop on the ground is what they get for "probably" forcing you to kill yourself. You'll lose the 30 solar (As I've sometimes spawned from the ship with 0 solar) but they won't automatically get it. And neither will the teammates.

Comment: wrong... they do receive the solar